# How to disable Eclipse splash screen?

Tags: eclipse

I want to disable the Eclipse splash screen because it always gets in my way..

How do I disable the Eclipse splash screen?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Run eclipse with the `-nosplash` option.

Comment: @ztatic, if this answers your question, please mark it as the answer. If it does not, please mention that also, and I will try again.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to permanently set a nosplash option you can edit the "eclipse.ini" file in the eclipse root dir and among the other options add "-nosplash".

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the correct way to find and change the eclipse splash screen.

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-change-eclipse-splash-welcome-screen-image/

Works even for the lastest Oxygen release on macOS Sierra!